# Why oracle DB does not update the fileds

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I do not know what is wrong with this query but it does not give any error and does not update the row. ENDDATETIME field datatype is TIMESTAMP.

UPDATE TEST_BANK set STATUS = 'RECEIVED', ENDDATETIME = '16-JUN-15 11.21.06.000000000' WHERE ENDDATETIME = null ;

[image]

[image: See the attached screenshot]

Comment: yes as andy mentioned send us an sql for it .. and I guess the problem with enddatetime condition

Comment: The clause to check if "anything = null" is ALWAYS false in Oracle. One null does not ever equal another null. It is like asking "is this unknown value equal to that unknown value?" The answer is "don't know". Use "IS NULL". That is asking "is this value unknown?" The answer to that can be yes.

Comment: In addition to all the suggestions for changing to IS NULL, you should also make sure you explicitly convert your strings to the timestamp format, rather than relying on implicit conversions based on your nls parameters (which could differ from person to person!). And use 4 digit years; I know Y2K was 15 years ago, but that's no excuse! eg. `ENDDATETIME = to_timestamp('16-JUN-2015 11.21.06', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24.mi.ss')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe in Oracle the syntax for checking for null is as following

```
 WHERE ENDDATETIME IS NULL
```

instead of the

```
 WHERE ENDDATETIME = NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
UPDATE TEST_BANK set STATUS = 'RECEIVED', ENDDATETIME = '16-JUN-15 11.21.06.000' WHERE ENDDATETIME is null ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ENDDATETIME format is wrong, hence its not selected.

Just copy paste the column value, and paste it in where clause ..it will work

Are you able to get the result

Select * from TEST_BANK WHERE ENDDATETIME = null ;

Use IS NULL  instead of  = null

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare NULL values. You'll need the "IS" operator.

```
UPDATE TEST_BANK 
   SET STATUS = 'RECEIVED', 
       ENDDATETIME = '16-JUN-15 11.21.06.000000000' 
 WHERE ENDDATETIME IS NULL ;
```

To explain this:
Assume Mr. Little and Mr. Large. You don't know how tall they are (size is null). Now can you positively state that they are of the same size?
If not, they won't be "selected" when compared.
Hence you need a comparion function to test if the value is unknown, which is what the "IS NULL" does.

Answer (score 1):

Operator is always applied on data while NULL is predicate in oracle. So it won't be worked with operator.

When ever you want to deal with NULL always use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

**Nulls with Comparison Conditions**

To test for nulls, use only the comparison conditions IS NULL and IS NOT NULL. If you use any other condition with nulls and the result depends on the value of the null, then the result is UNKNOWN. Because null represents a lack of data, a null cannot be equal or unequal to any value or to another null. However, Oracle considers two nulls to be equal when evaluating a DECODE function. Please refer to [DECODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm#i1017437) for syntax and additional information.

Oracle also considers two nulls to be equal if they appear in compound keys. That is, Oracle considers identical two compound keys containing nulls if all the non-null components of the keys are equal.